# ¿How to create text slider animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I have developed an slide automatic, very simple indeed.

I would like to add animation effects to the text, as this examples:

[Demo 1](http://wowslider.com/es/css-slider-aqua-flip-demo.html)

[Demo 2](http://cssslider.com/non-jquery-gallery-13.html)

could help with some example or step that I must follow to adapt the effects of animation in the slide

Code complete:

```js
$(function() {
  var SliderModule = (function() {
    var pb = {};
    //Defaul #slider > div
    pb.el = $('#slider > .carousel');
    pb.items = {
      panel: pb.el
    }

    var SliderInterval,
        currentSlider = 0,
        nextSlider = 1,
        lengthSlider = pb.items.panel.length;

    // Initialize
    pb.init = function(settings) {
      this.settings = settings || {duration: 8000} 
      var output = '';

      SliderInit();

      for(var i = 0; i < lengthSlider; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          output += '<div class="active"></div>'; 
        } else {
          output += '<div></div>';
        }
      }
    }

    var SliderInit = function() {
      $("#barra").animate({
          width:"100%"
        }, 
        pb.settings.duration,
        "linear",
        pb.startSlider
      );                     
    }

    pb.startSlider = function() {
      $("#barra").css("width", 0);
      var panels = pb.items.panel,
          controls = $('#slider-controls div');

      if (nextSlider >= lengthSlider) {
        nextSlider = 0;
        currentSlider = lengthSlider-1;
      }

      controls.removeClass('active').eq(nextSlider).addClass('active');
      panels.eq(currentSlider).fadeOut('slow');
      panels.eq(nextSlider).fadeIn('slow');

      currentSlider = nextSlider;
      nextSlider += 1; 
      SliderInit();
    }

    var changePanel = function(id) {
      $("#barra").stop().css("width", 0);
      var panels = pb.items.panel,
          controls = $('#slider-controls div');

      if (id >= lengthSlider) {
        id = 0;
      } else if (id < 0) {
        id = lengthSlider-1;
      }

      controls.removeClass('active').eq(id).addClass('active');
      panels.eq(currentSlider).fadeOut('slow');
      panels.eq(id).fadeIn('slow');

      currentSlider = id;
      nextSlider = id+1;

      SliderInit();
    }


    return pb;
  }());
  SliderModule.init({duration: 7000});
});
```

```css
/*!
 * @Design slider
 */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 548px !important;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slider-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color:#FFF;
}

.slider-wrapper  {
  z-index: 90;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-wrapper > div {
  display: none;
}

div.slide-current {
  display: block;
}

.slider-wrapper div .item {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.slider-inner {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.carousel-content {
  text-align: center;
}

#slider .slider-inner h2 {
    margin-top: 180px;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-image: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

#slider .slider-inner .btn {
  font-size: 18px;
  border-width: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #72C05B;
  border-color: #72C05B;
}

#barra {
  width: 0%;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
  background: #00c5b9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slide">
  <div id="slider" class="slider-wrapper">
    <div class="carousel slide-current">
      <div class="item" style="background-image: url('http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/slider/bg1.jpg');">
        <div class="slider-inner">
          <h2>Hello!!! How to create text animation</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel">
      <div class="item" style="background-image: url('http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/slider/bg2.jpg');">
        <div class="slider-inner">
          <h2>Hello!!! How to create text animation 2</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel">
      <div class="item" style="background-image: url('http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/slider/bg1.jpg');">
        <div class="slider-inner">
          <h2>Hello!!! How to create text animation 3</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="barra"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For your text animation use this css it will help you to build you text animation. This will work for text/image and html elements also.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">            
<style>
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/*
==============================================
CSS3 ANIMATION CHEAT SHEET
==============================================

Made by NK Chaudhary


Questions, comments, concerns, love letters:
nkchaudhary13@gmail.com
==============================================
*/

/*
==============================================
slideDown
==============================================
*/

.logo{
  height: 52px;
    margin-top: -15px;
 }
.logo:hover{
 opacity:0.8;
  transiftion:1s;
 }

.slideDown{
 animation-name: slideDown;
 -webkit-animation-name: slideDown; 

 animation-duration: 1s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

 animation-timing-function: ease; 
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease; 

 visibility: visible !important;      
}

@keyframes slideDown {
 0% {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
 }
 50%{
  transform: translateY(8%);
 }
 65%{
  transform: translateY(-4%);
 }
 80%{
  transform: translateY(4%);
 }
 95%{
  transform: translateY(-2%);
 }   
 100% {
  transform: translateY(0%);
 }  
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideDown {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
 }
 50%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(8%);
 }
 65%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-4%);
 }
 80%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(4%);
 }
 95%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-2%);
 }   
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
 } 
}

/*
==============================================
slideUp
==============================================
*/


.slideUp{
 animation-name: slideUp;
 -webkit-animation-name: slideUp; 

 animation-duration: 1s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

 animation-timing-function: ease; 
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;

 visibility: visible !important;   
}

@keyframes slideUp {
 0% {
  transform: translateY(100%);
 }
 50%{
  transform: translateY(-8%);
 }
 65%{
  transform: translateY(4%);
 }
 80%{
  transform: translateY(-4%);
 }
 95%{
  transform: translateY(2%);
 }   
 100% {
  transform: translateY(0%);
 } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideUp {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
 }
 50%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-8%);
 }
 65%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(4%);
 }
 80%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-4%);
 }
 95%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(2%);
 }   
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
 } 
}

/*
==============================================
slideLeft
==============================================
*/


.slideLeft{
 animation-name: slideLeft;
 -webkit-animation-name: slideLeft; 

 animation-duration: 1s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;  

 visibility: visible !important; 
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
 0% {
  transform: translateX(150%);
 }
 50%{
  transform: translateX(-8%);
 }
 65%{
  transform: translateX(4%);
 }
 80%{
  transform: translateX(-4%);
 }
 95%{
  transform: translateX(2%);
 }   
 100% {
  transform: translateX(0%);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideLeft {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(150%);
 }
 50%{
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-8%);
 }
 65%{
  -webkit-transform: translateX(4%);
 }
 80%{
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-4%);
 }
 95%{
  -webkit-transform: translateX(2%);
 }   
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
 }
}

/*
==============================================
slideRight
==============================================
*/


.slideRight{
 animation-name: slideRight;
 -webkit-animation-name: slideRight; 

 animation-duration: 1s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;  

 visibility: visible !important; 
}

@keyframes slideRight {
 0% {
  transform: translateX(-150%);
 }
 50%{
  transform: translateX(8%);
 }
 65%{
  transform: translateX(-4%);
 }
 80%{
  transform: translateX(4%);
 }
 95%{
  transform: translateX(-2%);
 }   
 100% {
  transform: translateX(0%);
 } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideRight {
 0% {

  -webkit-transform: translateX(-150%);
 }
 50%{
  -webkit-transform: translateX(8%);
 }
 65%{
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-4%);
 }
 80%{
  -webkit-transform: translateX(4%);
 }
 95%{
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-2%);
 }   
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
 }
}

/*
==============================================
slideExpandUp
==============================================
*/


.slideExpandUp{
 animation-name: slideExpandUp;
 -webkit-animation-name: slideExpandUp; 

 animation-duration: 1.6s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1.6s;

 animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease -out;

 visibility: visible !important; 
}

@keyframes slideExpandUp {
 0% {
  transform: translateY(100%) scaleX(0.5);
 }
 30%{
  transform: translateY(-8%) scaleX(0.5);
 } 
 40%{
  transform: translateY(2%) scaleX(0.5);
 }
 50%{
  transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1.1);
 }
 60%{
  transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(0.9);  
 }
 70% {
  transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1.05);
 }   
 80%{
  transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(0.95);  
 }
 90% {
  transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1.02);
 } 
 100%{
  transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1);  
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideExpandUp {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%) scaleX(0.5);
 }
 30%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-8%) scaleX(0.5);
 } 
 40%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(2%) scaleX(0.5);
 }
 50%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1.1);
 }
 60%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(0.9);  
 }
 70% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1.05);
 }   
 80%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(0.95);  
 }
 90% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1.02);
 } 
 100%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1);  
 }
}

/*
==============================================
expandUp
==============================================
*/


.expandUp{
 animation-name: expandUp;
 -webkit-animation-name: expandUp; 

 animation-duration: 0.7s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 0.7s;

 animation-timing-function: ease; 
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;  

 visibility: visible !important; 
}

@keyframes expandUp {
 0% {
  transform: translateY(100%) scale(0.6) scaleY(0.5);
 }
 60%{
  transform: translateY(-7%) scaleY(1.12);
 }
 75%{
  transform: translateY(3%);
 } 
 100% {
  transform: translateY(0%) scale(1) scaleY(1);
 } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes expandUp {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%) scale(0.6) scaleY(0.5);
 }
 60%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-7%) scaleY(1.12);
 }
 75%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(3%);
 } 
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scale(1) scaleY(1);
 } 
}

/*
==============================================
fadeIn
==============================================
*/

.fadeIn{
 animation-name: fadeIn;
 -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; 

 animation-duration: 1.5s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;

 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;  

 visibility: visible !important; 
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
 0% {
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0.0;  
 }
 60% {
  transform: scale(1.1); 
 }
 80% {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  opacity: 1; 
 } 
 100% {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1; 
 }  
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0.0;  
 }
 60% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 }
 80% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  opacity: 1; 
 } 
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1; 
 }  
}

/*
==============================================
expandOpen
==============================================
*/


.expandOpen{
 animation-name: expandOpen;
 -webkit-animation-name: expandOpen; 

 animation-duration: 1.2s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1.2s;

 animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; 

 visibility: visible !important; 
}

@keyframes expandOpen {
 0% {
  transform: scale(1.8);  
 }
 50% {
  transform: scale(0.95);
 } 
 80% {
  transform: scale(1.05);
 }
 90% {
  transform: scale(0.98);
 } 
 100% {
  transform: scale(1);
 }   
}

@-webkit-keyframes expandOpen {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);  
 }
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
 } 
 80% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
 }
 90% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.98);
 } 
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 }     
}

/*
==============================================
bigEntrance
==============================================
*/


.bigEntrance{
 animation-name: bigEntrance;
 -webkit-animation-name: bigEntrance; 

 animation-duration: 1.6s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1.6s;

 animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; 

 visibility: visible !important;   
}

@keyframes bigEntrance {
 0% {
  transform: scale(0.3) rotate(6deg) translateX(-30%) translateY(30%);
  opacity: 0.2;
 }
 30% {
  transform: scale(1.03) rotate(-2deg) translateX(2%) translateY(-2%);  
  opacity: 1;
 }
 45% {
  transform: scale(0.98) rotate(1deg) translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
  opacity: 1;
 }
 60% {
  transform: scale(1.01) rotate(-1deg) translateX(0%) translateY(0%);  
  opacity: 1;
 } 
 75% {
  transform: scale(0.99) rotate(1deg) translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
  opacity: 1;
 }
 90% {
  transform: scale(1.01) rotate(0deg) translateX(0%) translateY(0%);  
  opacity: 1;
 } 
 100% {
  transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
  opacity: 1;
 }  
}

@-webkit-keyframes bigEntrance {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.3) rotate(6deg) translateX(-30%) translateY(30%);
  opacity: 0.2;
 }
 30% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.03) rotate(-2deg) translateX(2%) translateY(-2%);  
  opacity: 1;
 }
 45% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.98) rotate(1deg) translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
  opacity: 1;
 }
 60% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.01) rotate(-1deg) translateX(0%) translateY(0%);  
  opacity: 1;
 } 
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.99) rotate(1deg) translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
  opacity: 1;
 }
 90% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.01) rotate(0deg) translateX(0%) translateY(0%);  
  opacity: 1;
 } 
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
  opacity: 1;
 }    
}

/*
==============================================
hatch
==============================================
*/

.hatch{
 animation-name: hatch;
 -webkit-animation-name: hatch; 

 animation-duration: 2s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;

 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

 transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%; 

 visibility: visible !important;  
}

@keyframes hatch {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(0deg) scaleY(0.6);
 }
 20% {
  transform: rotate(-2deg) scaleY(1.05);
 }
 35% {
  transform: rotate(2deg) scaleY(1);
 }
 50% {
  transform: rotate(-2deg);
 } 
 65% {
  transform: rotate(1deg);
 } 
 80% {
  transform: rotate(-1deg);
 }  
 100% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }         
}

@-webkit-keyframes hatch {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scaleY(0.6);
 }
 20% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg) scaleY(1.05);
 }
 35% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg) scaleY(1);
 }
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
 } 
 65% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(1deg);
 } 
 80% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg);
 }  
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }  
}


/*
==============================================
bounce
==============================================
*/


.bounce{
 animation-name: bounce;
 -webkit-animation-name: bounce; 

 animation-duration: 1.6s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1.6s;

 animation-timing-function: ease; 
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease; 

 transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;  
}

@keyframes bounce {
 0% {
  transform: translateY(0%) scaleY(0.6);
 }
 60%{
  transform: translateY(-100%) scaleY(1.1);
 }
 70%{
  transform: translateY(0%) scaleY(0.95) scaleX(1.05);
 }
 80%{
  transform: translateY(0%) scaleY(1.05) scaleX(1);
 } 
 90%{
  transform: translateY(0%) scaleY(0.95) scaleX(1);
 }    
 100%{
  transform: translateY(0%) scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
 } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleY(0.6);
 }
 60%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%) scaleY(1.1);
 }
 70%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleY(0.95) scaleX(1.05);
 }
 80%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleY(1.05) scaleX(1);
 } 
 90%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleY(0.95) scaleX(1);
 }    
 100%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
 }  
}


/*
==============================================
pulse
==============================================
*/

.pulse{
 animation-name: pulse;
 -webkit-animation-name: pulse; 

 animation-duration: 1.5s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;

 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
 0% {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  opacity: 0.7;  
 }
 50% {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1; 
 } 
 100% {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  opacity: 0.7; 
 }   
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
  opacity: 0.7;  
 }
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1; 
 } 
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
  opacity: 0.7; 
 }   
}

/*
==============================================
floating
==============================================
*/

.floating{
 animation-name: floating;
 -webkit-animation-name: floating;

 animation-duration: 1.5s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;

 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes floating {
 0% {
  transform: translateY(0%); 
 }
 50% {
  transform: translateY(8%); 
 } 
 100% {
  transform: translateY(0%);
 }   
}

@-webkit-keyframes floating {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); 
 }
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(8%); 
 } 
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
 }   
}

/*
==============================================
tossing
==============================================
*/

.tossing{
 animation-name: tossing;
 -webkit-animation-name: tossing; 

 animation-duration: 2.5s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 2.5s;

 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes tossing {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(-4deg); 
 }
 50% {
  transform: rotate(4deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(-4deg); 
 }      
}

@-webkit-keyframes tossing {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg); 
 }
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg); 
 }    
}

/*
==============================================
pullUp
==============================================
*/

.pullUp{
 animation-name: pullUp;
 -webkit-animation-name: pullUp; 

 animation-duration: 1.1s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1.1s;

 animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; 

 transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;   
}

@keyframes pullUp {
 0% {
  transform: scaleY(0.1);
 }
 40% {
  transform: scaleY(1.02);
 }
 60% {
  transform: scaleY(0.98);
 }
 80% {
  transform: scaleY(1.01);
 }
 100% {
  transform: scaleY(0.98);
 }    
 80% {
  transform: scaleY(1.01);
 }
 100% {
  transform: scaleY(1);
 }       
}

@-webkit-keyframes pullUp {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
 }
 40% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
 }
 60% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
 }
 80% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.01);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
 }    
 80% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.01);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
 }  
}

/*
==============================================
pullDown
==============================================
*/

.pullDown{
 animation-name: pullDown;
 -webkit-animation-name: pullDown; 

 animation-duration: 1.1s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1.1s;

 animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; 

 transform-origin: 50% 0%;
 -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;   
}

@keyframes pullDown {
 0% {
  transform: scaleY(0.1);
 }
 40% {
  transform: scaleY(1.02);
 }
 60% {
  transform: scaleY(0.98);
 }
 80% {
  transform: scaleY(1.01);
 }
 100% {
  transform: scaleY(0.98);
 }    
 80% {
  transform: scaleY(1.01);
 }
 100% {
  transform: scaleY(1);
 }       
}

@-webkit-keyframes pullDown {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
 }
 40% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
 }
 60% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
 }
 80% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.01);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
 }    
 80% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.01);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
 }  
}

/*
==============================================
stretchLeft
==============================================
*/

.stretchLeft{
 animation-name: stretchLeft;
 -webkit-animation-name: stretchLeft; 

 animation-duration: 1.5s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;

 animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; 

 transform-origin: 100% 0%;
 -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%; 
}

@keyframes stretchLeft {
 0% {
  transform: scaleX(0.3);
 }
 40% {
  transform: scaleX(1.02);
 }
 60% {
  transform: scaleX(0.98);
 }
 80% {
  transform: scaleX(1.01);
 }
 100% {
  transform: scaleX(0.98);
 }    
 80% {
  transform: scaleX(1.01);
 }
 100% {
  transform: scaleX(1);
 }       
}

@-webkit-keyframes stretchLeft {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.3);
 }
 40% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.02);
 }
 60% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.98);
 }
 80% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.01);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.98);
 }    
 80% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.01);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
 }  
}

/*
==============================================
stretchRight
==============================================
*/

.stretchRight{
 animation-name: stretchRight;
 -webkit-animation-name: stretchRight; 

 animation-duration: 1.5s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;

 animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; 

 transform-origin: 0% 0%;
 -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;   
}

@keyframes stretchRight {
 0% {
  transform: scaleX(0.3);
 }
 40% {
  transform: scaleX(1.02);
 }
 60% {
  transform: scaleX(0.98);
 }
 80% {
  transform: scaleX(1.01);
 }
 100% {
  transform: scaleX(0.98);
 }    
 80% {
  transform: scaleX(1.01);
 }
 100% {
  transform: scaleX(1);
 }       
}

@-webkit-keyframes stretchRight {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.3);
 }
 40% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.02);
 }
 60% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.98);
 }
 80% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.01);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.98);
 }    
 80% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.01);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
 }  
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="timeline-image pulse">
                               <h2 class="section-heading">My Amazing Team</h2>
                            </div>
</body>
</html>
```